# Cannot access apache webserver running on home network from internet

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

I am trying to setup apache web server in my home network. I followed the instructions found at http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/hostmyown.html. I have a d-link dir-601 router with a cable internet connection.

I am able to connect to the web server from my LAN using the url pointing to my server's ip 192.168.0.103 in the web browser.

but when I am trying to browse the same with my phone on 3G network, I get a message "server cannot be found".

My Public IP starts with 61.xx.xxx.xxx and my router has an IP of 192.168.0.1

Could anyone please help me in figuring out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The most common issue is that your firewall/router blocks this kind of incoming connection. Try setting a port forwarding from any IP, port 80 to port 80 (or whatever port you have configured your server to use) in your router and temporarily disable your Windows or other firewall, then try again. If it works then, enable your firewall and try again. If it doesn't work then, tell your firewall to accept incoming connections on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is not connected directly to your LAN. This means that your entire network is inaccessible from your phone. The whole point of your router is to make your LAN inaccessible from the Internet.

You have two options:

1. Connect your phone directly to your LAN with a wireless router or access point.
2. Enable port forwarding on your router to give anyone on the Internet access to your web server.