# Port Forward: Cannot access network device from internet

Tags: router, port-forwarding, dvr

I have a DVR which is connected to a router.

Router IP 192.168.1.1
Router Settings page: 192.168.1.1 Port 80
DVR IP: 192.168.1.114
DVR Video Client page: 192.168.1.114 Port 2800

Port Forwarding:
Router: Trendchip HG250
Forwarded: Port 2800 to 192.168.1.114:2800
Using the guide at [portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/TrendChip/HG520/HG520index.htm)
[image: portforwarddvr]

I then checked whether the ports are open or not on http://ping.eu/port-chk/
Port 2800 is shown as open.

On the same LAN, I can access the DVR page, by pointing my browser to 192.168.1.114:2800.

My public ip is 59.xxx.xxx.xxx. When I access 59.xxx.xxx.xxx, I get my router setting page(understandable, as it is at port 80 of 192.168.1.1). However when I try to access, 59.xxx.xxx.xxx:2800, I get a "Page cannot be displayed" error.

I have tried accessing 192.168.11:2800 from within the lan, which also gives me an error. I am new to port forwarding. What am I doing wrong? How do I get to my DVR Video page on  192.168.1.114:2800, using the ip 59.xxx.xxx.xxx:2800?

I have tried disabling the firewall in the router. I have tried restarting the dvr and the router.

Note:The ip 59.x.x.x, is dynamic, current ip was confirmed before testing. dvr supports ddns, which is working at example.dyndns.org. Router page opens on example.dyndns.org, 
page cannot be displayed error on example.dyndns.org:2800.

I have been through this question [Cannot access apache webserver running on home network from internet](https://superuser.com/questions/225683/cannot-access-apache-webserver-running-on-home-network-from-internet) which suggests disabling the router and windows firewall. In my case I have disabled the router firewall. I could not find a firewall in the DVR interface.The DVR is a CCTV DVR. Chinese make, unbranded. Model Number JA7208

Comment: Some routers don't like it when you try to access an internal computer (i.e. your DVR) using the external IP from within the network.  Get a friend to test, or use a smartphone or a neighbours open WiFi to test.

Comment: What's the make and model of the DVR? Are there any other services on the DVR that might be conflicting with other ports? Does it have it's own webserver that might be conflicting with the default port of 80 on the router?

Comment: @Moif Chinese Unbranded DVR. Model Number JA7208. It has its own webserver. I have set it to use port 2800. Additionally 3800 and 4800 are the ports which the smartphone app(Meye) uses to connect to the dvr feed using.

Comment: @MBraedley Can you post the comment as an answer? That worked. I used Opera mini which uses a proxy. Still have to test the other ports but I think this should do it. Also, I cannot access the router settings page when accessing from opera mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some routers don't like it when you try to access an internal computer (i.e. your DVR) using the external IP from within the network. Get a friend to test, or use a smartphone or a neighbours open WiFi to test.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but is your DVR getting a DHCP address, or a static one? I'm wondering if port forwarding will only work on static addresses.

Comment: static. 192.168.1.114 is the dvr ip.